# Getting corrupted data in inputstream.read

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

Ok so i'm trying to send files with the sockets. This is the code i got on the server side. The problem is that if i let this code run i will get some strange output liking missing bytes. I tried to add thread.sleep() inside the if statement this seemed to help some and only made the problem appear when it was handling larger files. I also tried to place a breakpoint on the line buffer = setbuffersize(binaryData, i, in); so i stopped after each file. This seemed to help the problem. So i guess the problem is that the code continue to read even if there is nothing to read (the client has had time to send it yet). I'm not really sure how to fix this. I tried to check if BUFFER_SIZE was as big as in.available() but it seems to stop sending after a while and never reach the BUFFER_SIZE.

So how do i get the code to wait for the data to be transmitted before it tries to read it?

```
while (byteRead != -1) {
commandlengh = msg.length();
binaryData = new byte[Integer.parseInt(ParameterValues.get(ParameterValues.size() - 1))];
in.read();
byte[] buffer = setbuffersize(binaryData, i, in);
while (in.read(buffer) != -1) {
for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++) {
binaryData[i] = buffer[j];
i++;
}
buffer = setbuffersize(binaryData, i, in);
if(buffer.length == 0)
{
Parameters.clear();
ParameterValues.clear();
i = 0;
commandlengh = 0;
break;
}
}
byteRead = in.read();
}
private byte[] setbuffersize(byte[] binaryData, int i, InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
    if(binaryData.length - i < BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        BUFFER_SIZE = binaryData.length - i;
    }
    else
    {
        BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the count returned by read() and assuming that it filled the buffer. Check the Javadoc. It isn't required to do that.

I can't make much sense of your code. You don't need all that to read from a socket. Just call read, check the result for -1; if so, stop; otherwise process bytes 0..count-1 of the buffer.